# Lane Detection in Real Time

Tags: conv-neural-network, detection, yolo

I am new in Deep Learning and i want to make project about lane detection system in real time.

What should i do it in pretrained model like YOLO ? Any ideas ?

I'll be glad if this question be answered.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some fast deep lane detection models like `CLRNet, UFLD, Resa, SCNN`. You can find their pre-trained models and inference code on their github repos. Most of the requires GPU though but you can run them on CPU too. [Here](https://github.com/Turoad/lanedet) you will find multiple model implementations in `python` and `PyTorch`.